How to authenticate Windows Authentication using Selenium WebDriver since latest chrome browser does not support URL authentication and in CICD
While trying to authenticate windows authentication, tried passing username and password in URL but this is not supported anymore with modern browser.
I can run fine using AutoIT/Robot framework but it won't work in CICD pipeline.
What is the solution

you can use an already logged in profile.  As long as the URL is in the internet's "Trusted/Local" zone, it shouldn't prompt.

How can I automate the profile login. Currently I am opening browser in Incognito. Is that the issue ?

I wouldn't think incognito would affect anything.  (default is basically incognito anyway since any session values are gone when driver quits.)
